# Error handling in std::ofstream while writing data

Tags: c++, ofstream

I have a small program where i initialize a string and write to a file stream:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  std::ofstream ofs(file.c_str());
  string s="Hello how are you";
  if(ofs)
     ofs<<s;
  if(!ofs)
  {
       cout<<"Writing to file failed"<<endl;
  }
  return 0;
 }
```

My diskspace is very less, and the statement  "***ofs<***" fails. So I know that this is an error logically.

The statement **"if(!ofs)"** does not encounter the above issue, hence I am unable to know why it failed.

Please tell me, by which other options I would be able to know that  **"ofs<** has failed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked that the `ofstream` is actually open before trying to `ofs <<`?

Comment: `ofstream::operator<<` will modify the internal state flags if it fails. Have you checked `ofstream::eof`/`bad`/`fail`?

Comment: @zenith: internal state flags will change if it fails to open the file. can you confirm if it fails while writing also? Request you to please show some cod e if possible.

Comment: Check the _Return value_ section [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/). Does that answer your question?

Comment: @zenith `ofstream::operator<<` will fail if there is a write error when attempting to write the data.  Because of buffering, this will generally not be on the output operation which fails.  _Usually_, it is sufficient to verify the status of the `ofstream` after `close` (when it is guaranteed that all data have been flushed); if you need a timely check, then you must  flush the stream first.

Comment: @zenith Well, it does't really specify what is meant by an error.  Buffering can easily cause the error state to be deferred.

Comment: And while I'm at it: verifying that output has succeeded is really one of the most basic elements of output in general.  A tutorial which doesn't insist on checking the output stream, at least after the close, is very deficient.

Comment: The most important point, of course, is that you cannot depend on the close in the destructor of `std::ofstream`; you must explicitly close the stream and test the status _after_ having closed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution like

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  std::ofstream ofs(file.c_str());
  string s="Hello how are you";
  if(ofs)
     ofs<<s;
  if(ofs.bad())    //bad() function will check for badbit
  {
       cout<<"Writing to file failed"<<endl;
  }
  return 0;
 }
```

You can also refer to the below links [here](http://www.math.hkbu.edu.hk/parallel/pgi/doc/pgC++_lib/stdlibug/err_7848.htm) and [there](http://www-control.eng.cam.ac.uk/~pcr20/www.cppreference.com/cppio_details.html)to check for the correctness.

Comment: I would  be very surprised if this worked.  You must either close the stream or flush it for the error to be detected.

Comment: Is there any chance that the stream is flushed when a lot of input has been written to the buffer? In that case, this might be a worthwhile check to add so that the program can terminate as soon as the error is noticed.

Comment: What does the `if (ofs)` do? I would expect that condition to be always true, since `ofs` is an object on the stack.

Comment: @jvriesem Probably a bit late, but in the case that the file couldn't be created in the constructor "std::ofstream ofs(file.c_str())", the object will be null and that's what is checked in the if

Comment: bad() will check only badbit, why not fail()? It is checking badbit or failbit both.

Answer (score 25):

In principle, if there is a write error, `badbit` should be set.  The
error will only be set when the stream actually tries to write, however,
so because of buffering, it may be set on a later write than when the error occurs, or even after
close.  And the bit is “sticky”, so once set, it will stay
set.

Given the above, the usual procedure is to just verify the status of the
output after close; when outputting to `std::cout` or `std::cerr`, after
the final flush.  Something like:

```
std::ofstream f(...);
//  all sorts of output (usually to the `std::ostream&` in a
//  function).
f.close();
if ( ! f ) {
    //  Error handling.  Most important, do _not_ return 0 from
    //  main, but EXIT_FAILUREl.
}
```

When outputting to `std::cout`, replace the `f.close()` with
`std::cout.flush()` (and of course, `if ( ! std::cout )`).

AND: this is standard procedure.  A program which has a return code of 0
(or `EXIT_SUCCESS`) when there is a write error is incorrect.

Comment: does your statement regarding EXIT_FAILURE mean that it is unsafe for a program to continue after a write error? I should think it is unsafe, but I just want to be extra sure.

Comment: @batbrat No. He means that a program should not return `0` (_i.e._ success) when there's been a problem.

Comment: @n.caillou Good point. We can return success when a problem occurs, if and only if we have handled it completely, right?

Comment: But how can we get a useful information about why write failed?

Comment: why replace close with flush??