# Saving A File to Directory C++

Tags: c++

So i've spent about 30minutes on this with no luck. Tried many ways of saving the file. It works when i save it into:
C:\Users\jsmit\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Password Generator\Password Generator

but not when i try and save it into:

C:\Users\jsmit\OneDrive\Documents

or:

C:\Users\jsmit\Documents\New folder

This is my code for saving a file:

```
void savePassword(string stringpassword, string site) {

ofstream out("C:\Documents\New folder\output.txt", ofstream::app); // DOESN'T WORK
out << site << ": " << stringpassword << endl; // This is where it saves the password into the text file
out.close(); // Closes file

}
```

If i put:

```
ofstream out("Password.txt", ofstream::app); // ofstream:app stops overwrite
```

it works.

EDIT:::: Allows me to save to H:\New folder but not C: drive? How to fix?

How do i make it so it saves it into: C:\Users\jsmit\OneDrive\Documents

Comment: Either use forward slashes, or escape the backslashes with an extra backslash.

Comment: Basically: \ -> \\ ([Printing the path](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ff223f074e3ab69) makes it obvious what the problem is, you even get compiler warnings!)

Comment: You need to escape the backslashes: `"C:\\Documents\\New folder\\output.txt"`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Tried this didnt work for some reason

Comment: @Borgleader Nope, i get no errors.

Comment: @IVIaximumPower "I get errors", what errors?

Comment: Are you sure the destination folder exists and your process has the write access to it, so it is allowed to create and/or overwrite the destination file?

Comment: @CiaPan Not sure, how do i check? It is able to write into the projects folder where the solution is made from.

Comment: Make sure the folder you are trying to write the file to exists. It will not be created in the process.

Comment: Hopefully [When will ofstream::open fail?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5835848/733637) or [Error handling in std::ofstream while writing data](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28342660/733637) contain useful answers. Or any of [Search for ofstream+fail](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ofstream+fail)...

Comment: @drescherjm The file does exist. I've done it so there is no txt file in the folder and there is a txt file called "output.txt" and both dont work.

Comment: @everyone So i'm able to save to my H drive put not my C: Drive? Im running VS as admin and am a Windows Admin???

Comment: Parts of your C: drive are protected by UAC.

Comment: @drescherjm even my documents? If i disable UAC will that fix it?

Comment: No but you seem be using a different path. I mean `C:\\Documents\\New folder` is not your profile. With that said Admin may not have rights on your user profile path.

Comment: Admin may not have rights on your user profile path. Run visual studio as a normal user. And use the correct path with \\ instead of \ for the path separator or just use /

Comment: @drescherjm Worked to allow me to write to C:\\Users\\jsmit\\Documents\\New folder\\output.txt but not OneDrive?

Comment: I have no experience with OneDrive. I just disable it since I already have have an unlimited cloud drive from a different provider.

Comment: @drescherjm Got it to save to OneDrive! Thanks for everyones help. Still no clue why it didnt work before. I just restarted my PC and seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the character `\` use `\\` or `/`

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C) for more details:

> In C, all escape sequences consist of two or more characters, the
>   first of which is the backslash, \; the remaining characters determine
>   the interpretation of the escape sequence. For example, \n is an
>   escape sequence that denotes a newline character. The remainder of
>   this article focuses on C; other programming languages are likely to
>   have different syntax and semantics.

Comment: ofstream out("C:\\Documents\\New folder\\output.txt", ofstream::app); // DOESN'T WORK
That doesn't work.

Comment: Nevertheless, using only '\' will never work ;) - take a look at Antonio's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just write into C: unless you are admin.

Use the shortcut for the Home Folder "%USERPROFILE%" to access this folder, then you can use "%USERPROFILE%\OneDrive\Documents"

Also, make sure the folder exists before writing any file into it. The folder won't be automatically created, you have to make it yourself.

Also, take a look at other answers, '\' character should be '\\'

Comment: I am an admin on this PC. Yes the file does exist. And the other answers don't work for some reason.

Comment: It's not "you" being the admin, but the process that is running the code the one that needs admin permissions. They aren't granted by default.

Answer (score 0):

Like others said \ is the escape character.  You need to use double backslashes when meaning for \ to be included.