# Error handling with QFile while writing data

Tags: c++, qt

I want to open a file, write to it, and properly check all error possibilities with `QFile`. I have [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28342660/error-handling-in-stdofstream-while-writing-data) how to this with `std::ofstream`:

```
std::ofstream f(...);
//  all sorts of output (usually to the `std::ostream&` in a
//  function).
f.close();
if ( ! f ) {
    //  Error handling.  Most important, do _not_ return 0 from
    //  main, but EXIT_FAILUREl.
}
```

Can I do error checking in a similar way if I use `operator<<()` with `QFile`?

What I have found is to use the `write` method and compare the return value with the length of string to write.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `operator<<` to write you'll need a stream like [`QDataStream`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html) or [`QtextStream`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html). And after each write you can check the stream status:

```
QFile file("out.txt");
if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    return;

QTextStream out(&file);
out << "The magic number is: " << 42 << "\n";
if (out.status() != QTextStream::Ok)
{
   // FAILED
}
```

Comment: It can not happen that no actual write happens because of buffering, and the error may occur later when the write is actually performed?

Comment: I think it could, but it's difficult because there are multiple levels of buffering and platform specific (see QIODevice::Unbuffered). You can try flushing and sync-ing. Or maybe even transactions.

Comment: @A.A, to that question, its always better to write ... `<< endl`  instead of ... `<<"\n"`, as it would  flush the stream and the device instantly.

Comment: @MohammadKanan. I prefer to explicitly call flush because `endl` makes the whole i/o unnecessary slow, except you really need it. But it doesn't help with the kernel buffers on linux for example.

Comment: @A.A, I have no idea why _slow_ lness could be experienced, but  in _Qt_ , `&endl` is equivalent to `stream << '\n' << flush;` .. instead of doing each separately

Comment: @MohammadKanan [CppCon 2017: Dietmar Kühl “The End of std::endl”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6WeEMlmrfOI)

Comment: @A.A, yes this is what I said in my comment, it would `flush()` ... your answer to _robert_ above was _You can try flushing_.